# Install Access Database Engine on Linux Centos

Tags: linux, ms-access, odbc

I want to read mdb file from linux centos.  To read that file, we must already install access data engine. Is there any access data engine for linux?

Now I'm using mdbtools to configure ODBC connect to mdb file inside Centos
I'm edit odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini inside etc directory.

#### odbc.ini:

```
[mydb]
Description = Microsoft Access Try DB
Driver = MDB
Database = /tmp/mydb.mdb
Servername = localhost
Username =
Password =
port = 5432
```

#### odbcinst.ini:

```
[MDB]
Description = MDB Tools ODBC
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmdbodbc.so.0
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libmdbodbc.so.0
FileUsage =
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
```

Then, in terminal, I type:

```
isql -v
```

result:

```
[IM010][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name too long
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My question, how to fix this? I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more about why you want to do this and why you need to run Linux in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding some extra command in terminal, like this:

```
isql -v mydb
and the result :
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

nb: "mydb" get it from odbc.ini file